# How to create a json with several arrays in php

Tags: php, json

I have several regions in my database table, I want to create a JSON that has arrays of each region. something like this:

```
var regions = {
    "region1": [
        { "lat": -1.325416, "lng": 36.669051 },
        { "lat": -1.244058, "lng": 36.730391 },
        { "lat": -1.392932, "lng": 36.768752 }
    ],
    "region2": [
        { "lat": -1.244058, "lng": 36.730391 },
        { "lat": -1.392932, "lng": 36.768752 },
        { "lat": -1.169516, "lng": 36.895608 }

    ],
    "region3": [
        { "lat": -1.392932, "lng": 36.768752 },
        { "lat": -1.169516, "lng": 36.895608 },
        { "lat": -1.390505, "lng": 36.810023 }
    ]
}
```

How do I do that? Thanks

This is my php code:

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$sql = "select lat,lon from regions";

$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('lat' => " ".$row[0],
'lng' => " ".$row[1]
));
}

$data = json_encode($result,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

echo $data;
?>
```

It gives a json for all regions.

Comment: What kind of database? How do you get the data to your php? What have you tried? What is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Invalid json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* do something like this:

First, get all regions.

Then for each region you have, get the remaining data.

```
$finalResult = array();
foreach ($regions as $region) {
    $sql = "SELECT lat, lon FROM regions WHERE regionid = $region['regionid'];";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    $result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result, array(
            'lat' => " ".$row[0],
            'lng' => " ".$row[1],
        ));
    }
    array_push($finalResult, array(
        $region['regionName'] => $result,
    ));
}

echo json_encode($finalResult, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```